# gRPC Java Client: get connected endpoint

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

Is it possible to get the actual connected endpoint from a channel?
I use a nameResolverFactory to get multiple possible endpoints for my channel. After a connection is established I want to know with which endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Channel does not provide a way to know which endpoint is being used before issuing an RPC. Each RPC may use a different connection (e.g., with round robin load balancer), so it's not a meaningful question to the Channel.

But if you do an RPC, after receiving the response headers you can call (e.g., from an interceptor) [`clientCall.getAttributes()`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ClientCall.html#getAttributes--) and then get [`Grpc.TRANSPORT_REMOTE_ADDR`](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/Grpc.html#TRANSPORT_ATTR_REMOTE_ADDR). That returns the endpoint address that particular RPC used.