How can I test that the factory options for a gRPC client have been set correctly in .NET?
Following along the gRPC client factory integration in .NET I can register a gRPC client as follows and set the factory up to create the client with specific factory options, in this case an address and a retry policy:
services.AddGrpcClient<Greeter.GreeterClient>(factoryOptions =>
  {
    factoryOptions.Address = new Uri(address);
    factoryOptions.ChannelOptionsActions.Add(opt =>
      opt.ServiceConfig = SetupGrpcRetryPolicy(retryPolicy));
  })

Now in the tests I want to verify that these options are set correctly. I can build a sample app with specific test settings for the address and retry policy, and get a client that has been created by that factory. Then I would like to test the set values:
var client = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<Greeter.GreeterClient>();

// what I want to test
Assert.Equals(expectedAddress, client.Address);
Assert.Equals(expectedRetryPolicy, client.RetryPolicy);

The problem is that this client does not have an Address or ChannelOptionsActions property, or anything similar. How can I access and verify that these values have been set correctly?

Background: In this application I have multiple gRPC clients and I want to ensure that a specific retry policy and address gets set for a specific gRPC client (or specific methods of that client). If this would be a simple HTTP client, I could read out these properties. But here I have seemingly no way to test if these values are set correctly to the client.

You want to get the remote endpoint of the response.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56732814/grpc-java-client-get-connected-endpoint

I get what you want to say, but that would only work for the address, not for client-side retry policy I think. It is also very hacky to add an interceptor to tests just to test the address.

The endpoint is part of the http response object.  c# is managed and you may not have access to the property like you would in c++.  Yes it may be a kludge, but you have limited access to all the properties in c#.

Thanks for the reply. This seems very counter-intuitive to the experience I have made so far with C#. Whenever I set a property to an object outside of it (-> a public setter), I should also be able to retrieve that property. When I set the address of an HTTP client in C#, I can retrieve that wherever I want. The only reason I can think of to not be able to do that would be sensitive information like a password.

c# hides properties.  For example with TCP only certain protocols are allowed while in c++ any protocol is allowed.  The c# library the protocol field is built that the protocol field has an enumeration where you can only select certain values.  c++ the field will accept any number.
